# Multiple checkboxes

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to create a simple checklist with multiple (over 30) checkboxes that can each be checked separately. My checkboxes are currently connected to only one BoolProperty which means I check one and they all get checked. Is creating a new boolproperty the only way to check them separately? If so that means with over 30 checkboxes my script is gonna be quite long. Is there an easier or shorter way to do this?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

# add your custom property to the Scene type
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = BoolProperty(
    name="Prop name",
        description="Checkbox fanatic",
        default = False) #sets checkbox state to true or false
        
 
class CBMENU_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Checklist" #name of the menu top
    bl_idname = "CBMENU_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "CheckList" #name of the tab menu
 
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sce = context.scene
        # draw the checkbox (implied from property type = bool)
        layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", text="Checkbox1") 
        layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", text="Checkbox2") 
        layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", text="Checkbox3") 

                
        
                
classes = [CBMENU_PT_main_panel
]
 
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
   
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You need a separate property for each Boolean value.

Comment: thank you, I've done it like that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way should be to use a [BoolVectorProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=boolvectorproperty#bpy.props.BoolVectorProperty) addressed via index

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolVectorProperty   ## changed

# MJF: Use a list to store the names you want to give each checkbox
checkbox_names = [ "Hi", "I", "am", "a", "checkbox"]

# add your custom property to the Scene type
checkboxes = 5   ## new 
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = BoolVectorProperty(   ## changed
        name="Prop name",
        description="Checkbox fanatic",
        size = checkboxes,   ## new
        default = (False,) * checkboxes)    ## changed    #sets checkbox state to true or false
        
 
class CBMENU_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Checklist" #name of the menu top
    bl_idname = "CBMENU_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "CheckList" #name of the tab menu
 
    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return True
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        sce = context.scene
        # draw the checkbox (implied from property type = bool)

        for idx in range(len(bpy.context.scene.my_prop[:])):       ## new 
            # MJF: CHANGED to use checkbox name
            layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", index = idx , text=checkbox_names[idx])   ## changed

#        layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", text="Checkbox2") 
#        layout.prop(sce, "my_prop", text="Checkbox3") 

bpy.utils.register_class(CBMENU_PT_main_panel)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you this is much shorter and cleaner. I'm sorry but I forgot to say that all checkboxes will be named differently (e.g. 1. pasta, 2. pizza, 3. sushi etc etc) , how would I add an ID to each checkbox?

Comment: @JeeperCreeper I've just made two small changes to the original script that will give you the ability to use unique names for each checkbox.  Since this works for you, you should accept this answer (click the checkmark sign next to the answer).  Be aware that this will only work for up to 32 checkboxes.

Comment: Apologies, new years holidays. Thank you @MartyFouts this is wonderful. Any ideas why it's limited to only 32?

Comment: No need to apologize. StackExchange takes some getting used to.  The 32 limit is because Blender uses the individual bits of an integer as the Boolean values. It can store one Boolean in one bit, and integers have 32 bits.